# How to Import XML to MS Access with Memo Data Type?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, import

I'm having error while using this code:

```
Application.ImportXML filename, acAppendData
```

By Default, it creates "RelevantResults" Table with "text" Datatype. Not all of the data was successfully imported because it is truncated.

I'm thinking of creating a table with one of the field is memo data type and append the XML. But how should I do this when it always create new table "RelevantResults"?

How should I define which table to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Access destination table exists, `ImportXML` with the `acAppendData` parameter preserves the structure of that table.  It adds the XML data to the table, assuming those data are compatible with the table fields' data types.

Create your *RelevantResults* table with memo data type where you need it, then run `ImportXML` to fill that table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many fields and tables to import, you may find it quick to import with errors, then delete the contents of each table (using Delete query) and finally go to design mode to change the data types. This will save you typing.